# Visual Studio 2012 Class View poor performance when using C++ class with operator()

Tags: visual-c++, ide, visual-studio-2012, operators

Hello I have a problem with Class View in Visual 2012. I have a simple class

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(void);
    ~Test(void);

    void operator()(int n)
    {
    }

    void operator()(double d)
    {
    }
};
```

When I open Class View and highlight this class it hangs whole IDE for couple of seconds. With Test class it is not that horrible, but adding few more operators makes things much worse.

Anyone knows how to improve performance with classes containing custom operator() ?

Edit:
Oh and the machine I am working on is quite powerfull:
CPU: Intel Core i7-2700 3,5GHz
RAM: 16GB
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT440

Everything on SSD. This should handle this kind of class quite fast ;)

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report problems like these.